# Renaming a placeholder heading in a pandas df with the string in the column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What I am looking for, but can't seem to get right is essentially this:
I'll read in a csv file to build a df. With the output being a table that I can manipulate or edit.
Ultimately, I'm looking for a method to rename the column header placeholders with the first "string" in the column.

Currently:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("NameOfCSV.csv")
df
```

Example Output:

| m1_name | m1_delta | m2_name | m2_delta | m3_name | m3_delta | ... | m10_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CO2 | 1 | NMHC | 2 | NaN | 1 | ... | NaN |
| CO2 | 2 | NMHC | 1 | NaN | 2 | ... | NaN |
| CO2 | 1 | NMHC | 2 | NaN | 1 | ... | NaN |
| CO2 | 2 | NMHC | 1 | CH4 | 2 | ... | NaN |

What I am trying to understand how to do is create a generic program that will grab the gas name within the column and rename the header "m*_name" and any other header corresponding to "m*_blah" with the gas name of that "m*_name" column.

Example Desired Output where the headers reflect the gas name:

| **CO2_name | CO2_delta | NMHC_name | NMHC_delta | NO2_name | NO2_delta** | ... | m10_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CO2 | 1 | NMHC | 2 | NaN | 1 | ... | NaN |
| CO2 | 2 | NMHC | 1 | NaN | 2 | ... | NaN |
| CO2 | 1 | NMHC | 2 | NO2 | 1 | ... | NaN |

I've tried playing around with the several functions (primarily .rename()), trying to find some examples of similar problems, and digging for some documentation but have been unsuccessful with coming up with a solution. Beyond the couple column headers here in the example there are about a dozen per gas name, so I was also trying to build a loop structure to find the headers with the corresponding m_number,"m*_otherHeader", to populate those headers also. The datasets I'm working with are dynamic and the positions of these original columns from the csv change position as well. Some help would be appreciated, and/or pointing me in the direction of some examples or the proper documentation to read through would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = df.drop_duplicates().set_axis([(f"{df[f'{x}_name'].mode()[0]}_{y}" if df[f'{x}_name'].mode()[0] != 0 else f'{x}_{y}') for x, y in df.columns.str.split('_', n=1)], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
 CO2_name  CO2_delta NMHC_name  NMHC_delta CH4_name  CH4_delta  m10_name
0      CO2          1      NMHC           2      CH4          1         0
1      CO2          2      NMHC           1      CH4          2         0
```

Comment: That's Fantastic! So, how could I edit/add to your code segment to translate all the header containing the corresponding "m#_" to have the gas name in them not just the "gas_name" header. for example:  m1_delta to CO2_delta, m2_delta to NMHC_delta, etc...

Comment: How would I handle the string manipulation/recognition if some of the headers, but not all have more than one underscore? So, most headers have one like: "m*_delta," but a few have two in the header like: "m*_ amount_uncertainty."  Would it be too much to ask to share a link for the documentation for how to do so as well. I would like to read up on how I could learn for the purposes of trying on my own.

Comment: Sure! [Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) is the documentation for `.str.split()`. About the multiple underscores - see my answer. I updated it to account for that. All you have to do is add `n=1` to the `.str.split()` call. That will ensure that it only splits by the first underscore, if there are multiple.

Comment: Final question I hope... If the code encounters an 'empty column' or a column with all zeros to not modify the header. For example: there are approximately 10 sets of columns, but only 7 or 8 of the sets are populated. Once it reaches the empty set 'm9_name', let's say, and cannot find a gas_name value I'll get a value error stating " 0 is not in range". is there a condition to use once it reaches an empty column to end the renaming process?

Comment: What would be the values of a such a column?

Comment: Yet to be populated, so it's automatically set to '0'.  Therefore, the header could still stay the same untouched. Like what you have shared, but as it is iterating through, once it reaches an all '0' m*_name column, it will stop moving along.

Comment: Okay, it's a little longer, a little uglier, but it should now :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240022/discussion-between-tygarn-and-user17242583).